# How to activate sessions in LUMEN 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, session, lumen, lumen-5.2

Im new to Lumen and i need to use the Session functionality, but based on the change log in the site. Sessions was excluded in the latest release,  I already looked up in the documentation of Lumen 5.2, it says that i should refer to Laravel way of activating session and something like that. my problem is I  have no experience using in Laravel too. Can anyone tell me, a step by step way to activate Lumen Sessions? 
or can anyone suggest a third-party library?

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055083/9618184)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in session support in Lumen. From the [release notes](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#5.2.0):

> ... **sessions and views are no longer included with the framework.** If you need access to these features, you should use the full Laravel framework.

You should [install](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation) the Laravel framework instead of Lumen and refer its [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session) on sessions.

Also, the default [PHP sessions](https://secure.php.net/manual/book.session.php) are still available.

Comment: oh thank you.i guess i should use the Authentication Provider.